# How to read an image into a Mat object using opencv c++ and android studio ndk?

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk

I have searched for a few hours now and can't seem to find an answer to my question(s). I have written the following lines of code in the android ndk(c++) and I am using the needed opencv libraries to accomplish the task.

```
void opening_images(){
    Mat image ;
    sillyString = "I have changed";
    String imagePath = "//drawable//ring.png";

    image = imread(imagePath,IMREAD_COLOR);

    if(image.empty()){
        sillyString = "Image not loaded";

    }
    else {
        sillyString = "Image loaded";

    }
}
```

I have tested this code in Qt with opencv and it works fine.At the moment the program in android studio returns the "Image not loaded" string. I think the main problem which is present is, the fact that I don't completely understand how to work with the file paths?  In android studio I have included a picture under res/drawable/ring.png. I am able to view this image using the java side of the app.

**Question 1**: Is the specified imagePath = "//drawable//ring.png" correct to access the ring.png file  ? 
**Question 2:** Is there any permissions needed allowing the ndk to access res folders ?
**Question 3:** Is there any similar methods to assign an image to a Mat object?

Any help will be appreciated.

Edit:

[image: The directories]

Comment: Why the double forward slashes in the path?

Comment: When I coded in Qt I read that c++ paths must be escaped. Therefore I used the same implementation in android ndk.

Comment: Escape symbol is a backslash (\\), not a forward slash(/) -- it's the former that needs a special treatment, not the latter...

Comment: Thank you, you are correct. I tested it with the c++ code, only one slash works. However it doesn't solve the problem in android.

Comment: Ya, I know, but it still seemed worth to mention. Now, is that path supposed to be absolute? As in, in the root directory, there is a subdirectory named "drawable" containing file "ring.png" ? Can you open it as a file (e.g. `fstream`) and read from it?

Comment: The directories are as follow: (Edit in question). I will quickly try to open the file as  suggested.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179313/discussion-between-johan-fick-and-dan-masek).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this was my first time using Android Studio there was much to learn. It took me a while but here is the answers to the questions that I posted.

**Question 1: Is the specified imagePath = "//drawable//ring.png" correct to access the ring.png file ?**

This is most definitely not the correct path to use when accessing images for the purpose of image processing etc.The drawable folder can still be used to update ex. an image view by setting the src of the image view to the image

```
 imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ring);
```

When working with images and Mat objects, I found it best to use the Android debugging bridge to copy the files to the SD card of the device. This link will provided you with the necessary steps to install the adb https://www.howtogeek.com/125769/how-to-install-and-use-abd-the-android-debug-bridge-utility/

When the images are done copying to the SD card. The file path can be found by making use of the built in Java function`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`. Which looks something like `/storage/emulated/0/YOUR_file` it depends on the location which was used to copy the files to.

**Useful tip:** Download *ES File Explorer* for the device to help navigate through the external or internal storage.

**Question 2: Is there any permissions needed allowing the ndk to access res folders ?**
The method which I used didn't need any permissions. However at the moment the NDK side cannot directly read an image from the SD card, the image must be passed from the Java side by making use of **assets** or by **passing the address of the image** which was read into the Mat object(Java side).

> Read and write permission is needed in order to access the SD card. This must be set in the manifest.xml and must be correctly implemented in the code. There are many great tutorials on YouTube.

**Question 3: Is there any similar methods to assign an image to a Mat object?**
This question seems redundant now, there are *many ways to skin a cat*.

In short, I think it is easier to stick to the Java side when using Opencv4Android and some form of image processing is needed.To get you started in java here is a small snippet from my code.

```
Mat image;
String imageInSD = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Pictures/Data/Birds/"(ImageFolders[i])+"/"+String.valueOf(id)+".png";

image = Imgcodecs.imread(imageInSD,Imgcodecs.IMREAD_COLOR);
```

Good luck!!

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at how BitmapFactory [decode resource works](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-1.6_r1/graphics/java/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.java#418) - you will see that getting bitmap from drawable still requires unpacking of a compressed image.

So answer to your q1: No it is not correct way to access ring.png, you will either have to download resource to your device or unpack it to byteArray and use `imdecode` instead of `imread`

Answer (score 1):

Another way to use saved image in NDK is follows,

Then drawable folder, you can save it in **assets** folder. This helps to access multiple images also easily.

Then `BitmapFactory.decodeStream` helps to take it as bitmap and `Utils.bitmapToMat` is used to convert **bitmap** image to **Mat** file.

Then this Mat file, you can pass to NDK and process it using OpenCV C++.

Thanks